# Extract a particular word from a text

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract the word following 'NN' in this particular sentence?

```
(ROOT (SBARQ [26.015] (WHNP [1.500] (WP [1.051] What)) (SQ[23.912] (VBZ[2.669]'s)
(NP [19.076] (PRP$ [3.816] your) (NN [9.843] thought))) (. [0.002] ?)))
```

So, when I parse this.. using Regex, I need to extract only the word *'thought'* out.

How do I do that?

My code:

```
String pattern = "\NN \[[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9])?\] (.)\)"; 
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern); 
Matcher m = r.matcher(st); while(m.find()) {System.out.println(m.group());}

output: (NN [9.843] thought))) (. [0.002] ?)))
```

But I want only *'thought'*

**Answer:**

Got it :-) thanks people.

```
String pattern = "NN \\[.*] (\\w+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(st);
while(m.find())
{System.out.println(m.group(1));}
```

**output**: thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regular expression will match the NN block, where the (.*) group will pick up 'thought'.

```
\(NN \[[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?\] (.*)\)
```

I always find that regular expression test beds are very useful for this kind of problem. I recommend using:
http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2):

Given that the format doesn't allow much kinky stuff, this should get the word:

```
\(NN \[[^\]]*\] ([^\)]*)\)
```

and then do s.th. like

```
if (matcher.find(yourstring)) {
  theword = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Seems on of the excaped braces was swallowed.. try this: `\(NN \[[^\]]*\] ([^\)]*)\)`